# How to merge multiple files based on a idenfitier into a big matrix using bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I have hundreds of files in a directory, named `File1`, `File2`, `File3`, ...,`File200`. Suppose I only have 3 files now, contents in these files are:

`File1`: (columns are separated by Tab)

```
[CITY]  [SCORE]
City1    110
City2    120
City3    130
City4    140
```

`File2`: (columns are separated by Tab)

```
[CITY]  [SCORE]
City1    210
City3    230
City4    240
```

`File3`: (columns are separated by Tab)

```
[CITY]  [SCORE]
City1    310
City5    350
```

Here the `[CITY]` column is an identifier, `[SCORE]` is a value term. I want to merge these files into one matrix based on the identifier column `[CITY]`, filling `NA` in missing cells,

`MergedMatrixFile`: (columns are separated by Tab)

```
[CITY]  File1    File2    File3
City1    110    210    310
City2    120    NA    NA
City3    130    230    NA
City4    140    240    NA
City5    NA    NA    350
```

How can I do this with `Bash`.

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: This is a good candidate for GNU awk. It has multidimensional arrays. You can use that to build up the matrix, and print it in an END block. Refer to [tag:awk] and click the "Learn more" link

Comment: Have a look at `join`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk and possibility of additional files

```
 awk 'FNR > 1 { 
                map[$1][FILENAME]=$2; # Create a two dimensional array with the city as the first index and the filename the second.
                fils[FILENAME]="" # Create an array of the file names
              } 
          END { 
                PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"
                printf "%s\t","[CITY]"; # Print the city header
                for (c in fils) { 
                                   printf "%s\t",c # Loop through each file name in fils and print as a header
                                };
                printf "\n";
                for (i in map) { 
                                 printf "%s",i; # Print the city columns
                                 for (j in fils ) { 
                                                     !map[i][j]?str[j]="NA":str[j]=map[i][j]; # Loop through the two dimensional array and if there is no entry for a given city/file name, set array str to NA (index file name) otherwise set to value in array
                                                     printf "\t%s",str[j] # Print the str variable
                                 } 
                printf "\n" 
                } 
              }' file1 file2 file3
```

One liner:

```
awk 'FNR > 1 { map[$1][FILENAME]=$2;fils[FILENAME]="" } END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc";printf "%s\t","[CITY]";for (c in fils) { printf "%s\t",c };printf "\n";for (i in map) { printf "%s",i;for (j in fils ) { !map[i][j]?str[j]="NA":str[j]=map[i][j];printf "\t%s",str[j] } printf "\n" } }' file1 file2 file3
```

Comment: In fact, I have hundreds of files rather than just 3 in this directory.

Comment: OK, I've amended the solution.

Comment: Thank you! A little problem:  we do not need a tab `\t` followed last column

Comment: OK, I've amended to place tabs before as opposed to after the strings

Comment: Still some bugs left. The first row in output is `[CITY] File2 File3 File1` rather than `[CITY] File1 File2 File3`. I don't find out reasons.

Comment: I've added PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc" to the code to set the array ordering. This will only work on GNU versions of awk though

Comment: Hi, it seems that this script still has some bugs. When it comes to big data, the result is wrong. For example, if I have 100 files, the results from this script and another python code are same. But when it comes to 1000 files, result from this script is wrong. It seems that the largest amount of the merged matrix from this script is ~ 1G in my server. I'm wondering if the problem is due to the limit of amount of the array in awk.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rather ugly script that is far from efficient and possibly buggy:

```
#!/bin/bash

TMP=$(mktemp -d)

# get the union of all city names
tail -q -n +2 File* | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u > ${TMP}/cities.txt

# fill in the missing entries for each file
for file in File*; do
    tail -n +2 ${file} | cat - <(diff <(awk '{print $1}' ${file} | sort) ${TMP}/cities.txt | grep '^>') | sed 's/^> \(.*\)/\1    NA/' | sort | awk '{print $2}' > ${TMP}/${file}
done

# put it all together
paste ${TMP}/cities.txt ${TMP}/File* > merged.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. I test the code, the main problem is the loss of filename in the merged matrix file.